# Macro/command for building a word-range in both directions?

Tags: vim, text-editor, sublimetext

I am afflicted with a disease where I am always left unsatisfied no matter how feature-complete a piece of software is.

I am quite happy with the ability to quickly delete/yank/change/etc a range of text starting from the cursor.

But there does not appear to be a good way to quickly yet precisely navigate the actual cursor in a way that I perceive optimal:

Consider when editing code (when editing prose this is a non-issue) one is dealing with heavy syntax with `'"[{(<` characters spread among spaces (I have abandoned tabs in favor of all spaces for flexibility, but it does not affect this). This means that any helpful way to hop among non-word chars is gonna skip across the code boundaries that one often needs to perform edit operations between.

So, while `b`, `e`, `w` and their shifted (reverse-motion) counterparts (and never-used-by-me `ge`/`gE`) are helpful to a degree, they don't provide helpful granularity to zero in.

Here's my idea: a mystery key X as an extension of the forward-searching `f` and `t` (and their backward-searching counterparts `F` and `T`), which takes two keypress arguments rather than one:

that, given this starting state, with the cursor lying on the `n` character in the second line:

```
watch: {
  files: ['<%= jshint.files %>'],
} //   Cursor Here ^
```

I can type `Xjs`, and what this will do is search left of the cursor for the first `j`, search right of the cursor for hte first `s`, and perform an operation on that range.

e.g. `cXjsfoo` yields

```
watch: {
  files: ['<%= foo %>'],
}
```

`cXjtbaz` yields (sometimes equivalent to `ciwbaz`, but more precise, as **`iw` depends on iskeyword!**)

```
watch: {
  files: ['<%= baz.files %>'],
}
```

`dX%%` yanks out `%= baz.files %` leaving (this is impossible even with `surround.vim` as `%` is not recognized as a match-pair, nor would I necessarily want it to be treated as one):

```
watch: {
  files: ['<>'],
}
```

and so on.

Perhaps another way to think of it is a retroactive method to move the cursor to a beginning spot after specifying a verb.

Yes, technically, it's not too hard to just do `F%df%`, but `dX%%` just makes better sense in my head, and as a result, `F%df%` is never actually faster for me than e.g. `hhhhhhhdf%`. Further consider `X` would be easily bound to a single key so it's actually two key presses that we save in that case.

I know I can do this with a keybinding with Sublime Text vintage mode; it's powerful enough. But what about Vim? Is it possible?

Comment: Alternatively I notice that the majority of the times that I feel a hankering for this type of a feature is when I am dealing with parameter lists and their pesky commas. Maybe a really nice parameter list editing plugin would help enough as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
onoremap <silent> X :<C-u>execute 'normal! vlF' . nr2char(getchar()) . 'of' . nr2char(getchar())<CR>
vnoremap <silent> X :<C-u>execute 'normal! vlF' . nr2char(getchar()) . 'of' . nr2char(getchar())<CR>
```

`<C-u>` clears the command line (in case `'<,'>` was automatically inserted); `execute 'normal!'` then evaluates the following expression and executes it as a normal command:

```
'vlF' . nr2char(getchar()) . 'of' . nr2char(getchar())
```

This waits for the next 2 keys (e.g. <kbd>j</kbd><kbd>s</kbd>) and concatenates them into `vlFjofs`, resulting in a text object spanning from the previous `j` to the next `s`. The `l` before `F` is necessary in case your cursor is currently on the first character you enter.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure about the pertinence of what you are asking. All the examples in your question are easily dealt with by using what's already in Vim.

1st example (`[x]` marks the cursor position):

```
    watch: {
      files: ['<%= jshi[n]t.files %>'],
    }

    ciWfoo

    watch: {
      files: ['<%= fo[o] %>'],
    }
```

2nd example:

```
    watch: {
      files: ['<%= jshi[n]t.files %>'],
    }

    ciwbaz

    watch: {
      files: ['<%= ba[z].files %>'],
    }
```

3rd example:

```
    watch: {
      files: ['<%= ba[z].files %>'],
    }

    di<

    watch: {
      files: ['<[>]'],
    }
```

Creating new text-objects is indeed fun and useful but make sure you are not overthinking it a little too much.